# Python finding element with Selenium

Tags: css, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

How can I find an element with Selenium
NOTE: the xpath sometimes changes
the code is here:

```
<input type="submit" value="Convert">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I get what you're asking..? the CSS selector would be `input[value="Convert"]`so you would use

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[value="Convert"]')
```